# How to select record by distinct column in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

There is one model named Book, I want to get all books, but all results have distinct column named 'author', how to do this ? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be by:

```
Book.select("DISTINCT(author)")
```

for more read this: [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

---

**Edit**

You can try: `find_by_sql` as

```
Book.find_by_sql("select * from books group by author")
```

Comment: But the result has only author column, i need all column of the model

Comment: or else it raises the ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError

Comment: thanks! it works. but i still confuse between "group by" and "distinct"

Comment: @why:- group by will return same as distinct.

Comment: another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699616/rails-generate-plugin-with-generator, I am using rail3.0.3, could you please review it?