# How to return distinct rows in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model Program containing fields program_title, department_id and date. I have inserted two rows having same program title and date but different department_id.

```
Insert into programs(program_title,date,department_id) Values ("prog1","4/2/2017","1");
Insert into programs(program_title,date,department_id) Values ("prog1","4/2/2017","2");
```

Now I want to return rows which will be distinct by program_title whatever be the department_id. I have tried,

```
@event_contents=Program.select(:id,:date,:program_title).distinct(:program_title)
```

But still it returns both the rows. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try: `Program.select(" distinct program_title, id, date, program_title" )`

Comment: tried it already. No luck!

Comment: what rails version are you using?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701911/how-to-select-record-by-distinct-column-in-rails3

Comment: Version 4.2.5.1

Answer (score 2):

SQL can only collapse rows where **all** values are the same when using `DISTINCT`. Because you are selecting `id`, which is different for every record, the rows are not distinct. E.g.:

```
---------------------------------
| id | program_title | date     |
---------------------------------
|  1 | prog1         | 4/2/2017 |
|  2 | prog1         | 4/2/2017 |
---------------------------------
```

You'll need to exclude the `id` from your `#select` for it to work:

```
Program.select(:date, :program_title).distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Program.all.distinct(:program_title).pluck( :id,:program_title,:date)
```

It will return data as array of elements though

Hope it helps